# Indwelled by the Holy Spirit — VS — not indwelled by the Holy Spirit according to the Calvinist?

Tags: reformed-theology, born-again

I will quote a few points that I found from [Regeneration in the Old Testament](https://www.monergism.com/thethreshold/articles/onsite/OTregeneration.html).

> 1. It can be clearly demonstrated that regeneration is an occurrence in both the Old and New testaments
> 2. But the INDWELLING of the corporate body by the Spirit presupposes the resurrection

Also from another source with the same title [Regeneration in the Old Testament](http://www.learnthebible.org/regeneration-in-the-old-testament.html)

> it is important to note that one could be born of the Spirit and yet
>   not be indwelled by the Spirit

The question :
*Is there a different result from the one who already born of the Holy Spirit BUT NOT indwelled by the Holy Spirit — versus — the one who already born of the Holy Spirit AND indwelled by the Holy Spirit ?*

Comment: Further down from your quote the author you quote says  '_Old Testament saints were probably not born of the Spirit as we are today_' 'Probable' in spiritual matters just isn't good enough. Nor does the author support any of his suppositions with solid scriptural exegesis. Thus, it all becomes mere opinion.

Comment: @NigelJ, I thought what the author means (in the second quote) is the same with number-2 in the first quote. Or do you mean that the first quote is also just an opinion ? So, both quotes actually are not reflecting a Calvinist teaching ? If yes, then I will reworded the question by asking if "born of Spirit that occur in OT times is not indwelled by the Holy Spirit" is just an opinion, then what is the Calvinist view about it (which is regarded that it's not an opinion) ?

Comment: @NigelJ, you wrote _"Nor does the author support any of his suppositions with solid scriptural exegesis"_. I'm sorry I don't know what you mean on "solid scriptural exegesis". But in both articles, the author did put some verses to support their opinion about born of Spirit in the OT.

Answer (score 3):

**Indwelled by the Holy Spirit — VS — not indwelled by the Holy Spirit according to the Calvinist?**

(Speaking as a Calvinist) the Holy Spirit surely indwelt believers before the resurrection.

So David said:  "Cast me not away from thy presence; and take not thy holy spirit from me."  (Psalm 51:11)  (See also 2 Peter 1:21.)

"Now if any man have not the Spirit of Christ, he is none of his."  (Romans 8:9)

From these I understand that the Holy Spirit was poured out after the resurrection in a measure not known before, but there is no difference otherwise between pre-resurrection and post-resurrection.

The author you have quoted does not speak on behalf of all calvinists; and calvinists do not have a single view on everything.

Answer (score 1):

This article by JAMES M. HAMILTON JR. (summarizing his PhD dissertation) sets forth six views:

https://www.thegospelcoalition.org/themelios/article/were-old-covenant-believers-indwelt-by-the-holy-spirit/

The article lists Theologians who subscribe to each view (except one hypothetical which the author could not find any proponents of).

From the article, here are the positions and their adherents (bolding and section labels are mine):

> **Basic continuity**. On the issue of the Spirit’s role in the lives of believers, some
> scholars see basic continuity from the old to the new covenant. These
> authors argue that the old covenant remnant was both regenerate and
> indweltby the Spirit. Adherents of this position include **John Owen**,
> **B.B. Warfield**, **Sinclair Ferguson**, **Dan Fuller** and **Leon Wood**.
>
> **Continuity with Heightened Experience post-resurrection**. Another set of scholars agrees that old covenant believers experienced
> both regeneration and indwelling, but seek to incorporate texts like
> John 7:39 into their understanding by using language that allows for a
> greater or heightened experience of the Spirit under the new covenant.
> Nevertheless, these scholars see no fundamental change in the way
> believers experience the Spirit when the new covenant is inaugurated.
> Interpreters who can be placed here include **Augustine**, **John Calvin**,
> **George Ladd**, **Dan Block** and **Wayne Grudem**.
>
> **OT saints Regenerate but not indwelt**. The third position is the midpoint of the possible views. These
> scholars indicate that they see OT saints as regenerate by the Spirit
> but not indwelt by the Spirit. From statements in their writings, it
> seems best to place here **Millard Erickson**, **J.I. Packer**, **Willem A.
> VanGemeren** and **Bruce Ware**.
>
> **OT saints Operated upon but not indwelt**. The next position is for those who see the old covenant remnant as
> operated upon but not indwelt by the Spirit. Unlike those in the
> previous category, these scholars stop short of using the word
> regeneration with reference to the old covenant faithful. Articulators
> of this view include **Martin Luther**, **Lewis Sperry Chafer**, **Craig
> Blaising**, **D.A. Carson** and **Michael Green**.
>
> **OT saints Not indwelt**. At the opposite end of the spectrum from those who affirm full
> continuity between the old and new covenant ministries of the Spirit
> would be those who affirm that the Spirit had nothing to do with the
> faithfulness of the old covenant remnant. Those who argue that OT
> saints were indwelt sometimes assume that this is the only alternative
> to their view, but I have not found anyone who takes this position.
>
> **No position on OT Saints and Holy Spirit**. There are, however, a number of interpreters who stress the new nature
> of the Spirit’s ministry after the Christ event but offer no
> explanation of how old covenant believers became and remained
> faithful. Here we find prominent dispensationalists such as **Charles
> Ryrie** and **John Walvoord**. Most scholars who have written on the
> Spirit from the perspective of NT theology fit here, as do several
> authors who have written both commentaries on John and studies
> specifically on the Spirit in John — **C.K. Barrett**, **Raymond Brown** and
> **Gary Burge**.

Some of the above are Calvinists (like John Calvin). As you can see, there is a considerable variation in views!

The article then dissects the evidence for and against the views. As you can see, Calvin himself believed that NT believers experience a heightened experience of the Holy Spirit, but not an essentially different one. However, not all Calvinists agree. Another quote from the article:

> Also, there are people who are soteriologically Calvinistic who argue
> that old covenant believers were not indwelt (Carson, Packer, Ware).

The author then goes on to argue the position that most believers in the OT were not indwelt by the Holy Spirit. The exceptions were prophets and key leaders, like Moses and David. Instead, for the people, God dwelt "with" his people, not "in" them.

However, he expresses the idea that people can be regenerated by the Holy Spirit (pre-resurrection) but not indwelt.

> And I will ask the Father and he will give you another Comforter, that
> he might be with you forever, the Spirit of Truth, whom the world is
> not able to receive, because it neither sees him nor knows him. You
> know him, because he is **with you**, and he will be **in you** (John
> 14:16–17).30

The distinction made by John is again between the Holy Spirit being with you and being in you.

Answer (score 1):

Without reading the sources you take a couple of quotes from, all I can flag up from what little is quoted is with respect to point 2 in the first quote.

It speaks of indwelling of ***the corporate body*** by the Spirit. This indicates a significant difference between how the spiritual Body of Christ (his Church) experiences the indwelling Holy Spirit, and how individuals may have their experience of the Holy Spirit's presence. There is a corporative experience which Paul speaks of. He starts by saying how husbands should related to their wives, in love:

“…even as Christ also loved the church, and gave himself for it, that he might sanctify and cleanse it with the washing of water by the word, that he might present it to himself a glorious church, not having spot, or wrinkle, or any such thing; but that it should be holy and without blemish…For we are members of his body, of his flesh, and of his bones… This is a great mystery: but I speak concerning Christ and the church.” Ephesians 5:25-32

This mystery is revealed in the New Testament, and it is the Holy Spirit who is at work with the corporate church – spoken of as “it”. This mystery was not revealed in the Old Testament, though clues were there. Only after the Holy Spirit was poured out in a particular way, at the ‘birth’ of the church that Pentecost day, was the mystery revealed. All Christians who have the indwelling Holy Spirit should also know of the corporate experience of the Holy Spirit at work in the church.

As for the second quote, from a different source (with the same title as the first source), there is no way this can be examined and responded to from a Calvinistic point of view without reading the whole section. There would need to be a significant increase in information from both your sources before a detailed answer could be given, but I will try to look at both sources next, to see if I can add anything worth-while.

EDIT – I’ve now seen both sources and would simply say that each article sets out to answer different questions from different individuals. Then you have asked your own question here on Stack. If you have read both articles and still remain confused, I suggest you contact monergism.com to put your question to them, and likewise with learntheible.com  It is their respective articles that you are still struggling with, so they would be the best ones to help you out.